# adding script in microsoft project 2010

Tags: vba, ms-project

i'm new to microsoft project 2010. Does anyone know if i can write scripts in microsoft project 2010 files? for example, i would like to change the text style of a specific cell when the difference of days between start column and finish column dates are bigger than 7 days. Could you please point me to any tutorial online?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed add VBA macros in Project 2010. You might find this [reference material](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms448515.aspx) a useful starting point.